# Is there a compareAndSet for != value (compareAndSetIfUnequal)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I often have the situation where there is an action to be triggered in case something is different than expected. Unfortunately compareAndSet is not suitable for this kind of atomic problem. I need something like compareAndSetIfUnequal. Currently I use something like the code below but I am afraid it is expensive:

```
private AtomicReference<T> atomic = new AtomicReference<T>(null);
public static void doIfUnequal(T obj) {                  
    if(atomic.getAndSet(obj) != obj) {
       doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: compareAndSetIfUnequal is functionally the same as a simple set, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're concerned about the repeated use of getAndSet in your example, I'd first like to remind you to profile code before worrying too much about it.  Your code is clean.

However, if you want to avoid the "set" part (and the related hardware overhead of the atomic operations), you'll need to loop this one yourself using get with compareAndSet:

```
private AtomicReference<T> atomic = new AtomicReference<T>(null);
public static void doIfUnequal(T obj) {
    T curVal;
    while((curVal = atomic.get()) != obj) {
        if(atomic.compareAndSet(curVal, obj)) {
            doSomething();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was aiming at setting costs, but I agree it is more theoretical looking for the optimum, I don't have problems in practice with it.

Comment: I sometimes ponder to myself, what if my code is running on a supercomputer with 10,000 processors and an unusually high latency between processing nodes, where atomic operations are sure to incur greater overhead?  How will it scale?  Then I realize I'm not working on a cure for cancer or modeling hurricanes and will probably not scale beyond two CPUs/40 cores.  Anyway, I appreciate the theoretical considerations as a thought experiment even if not needed in practice.

Comment: I hate the moment in coding a problem when I have to realize: damn I am not coding healing cancer, get on. ;-)